# Tensorflow CustomOp: multiprocessing not working for CPU

Tags: python, c++11, tensorflow, eigen

I am defining a custom Op in Tensorflow (Tensorflow 1.13.1) . The single thread version is working great, but I want to use multi-threads using `work_sharder.h` it first can find only one worker and then segfaults.

I am defining a shard function on the indexes of a flattened array:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <cfloat>

#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h"

#include "./work_sharder.h"

using namespace tensorflow;
typedef Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice CPUDevice;

REGISTER_OP("Minimal")
    .Input("input: float")
    .Output("shared_arr: float")
;

class MinimalOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit MinimalOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {

    const Tensor& input= context->input(0);
    auto input_flat = input.flat<float>();
    const int N = input_flat.size();

    // Create an output tensor of the right shape
    Tensor* shared_arr = NULL;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, input.shape(),
                                                     &shared_arr));
    // This tensor is going to be shared among threads
    auto shared_arr_flat = shared_arr->flat<float>();

    // Shard function on ranges
    auto shard = [&input_flat, &shared_arr_flat]
                  (int64 start, int64 limit) {
        for (int i = 0; start < limit; i++) {
            if ((input_flat(i))<0.){
                shared_arr_flat(i) = 0.;
            }}};

    std::cout<<"Shard definition was okay\n";
    const DeviceBase::CpuWorkerThreads& worker_threads = *(context->device()->tensorflow_cpu_worker_threads());
    std::cout<<"Number of workers = "<<worker_threads.num_threads<<"\n";
    const int64 shard_cost = N;
    Shard(worker_threads.num_threads, worker_threads.workers,
            N, shard_cost, shard);

  }};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("Minimal").Device(DEVICE_CPU), MinimalOp);
```

It compiles perfectly.
When running this multi-threaded code in python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


minimal_module = tf.load_op_library("./minimal.so")
tf_minimal = minimal_module.minimal

input_tensor = tf.constant(np.random.normal(size=(100, 100)).astype("float32"))
returned_tensor = tf_minimal(input_tensor)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(returned_tensor)
```

it prints: Number of worker = 1 and segmentation fault.
The output of `g++ --version` is:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

When using `multiprocessing` library in python it finds 12 workers.

I compile using:

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
TF_LFLAGS=( $(python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -undefined dynamic_lookup minimal.cc -o minimal.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

**EDIT:**

Following the comments I installed gcc 4.9 (4.8 doesn't exist anymore on brew and because some guy on the issue said the problem was a change from 5.x to 4.x).
I had some weird bugs because it could not find std library. So I had to do some other xcode install stuff, which fixed it.

Now during compilation (g++-4.9 instead of g++) I get lots of warnings (warning: section "__const_coal" is deprecated and the likes).

But it compiles, when I run it however I have this error:
`Symbol not found: __ZN10tensorflow12OpDefBuilder5InputESs`,

However it cannot be solved by removing the line -D _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0, -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 or even adding it.

So I cannot say that I have made any progress.

Comment: Thou shalt provide a [mre]!

Comment: I will, it has just proven difficult to write a mwe that makes sense.

Comment: I updated my question, it turns out the concurrent access was not the main problem, more multi-threads in general.

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you using? Looks very much as this open issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13308

Comment: I am using 1.13.1 adding it in the question.

Comment: Thanks @isp-zax looks like both issues look alike. What would you suggest to make sure this is indeed the same problem ?

Comment: (Except from the fact that it can find only one thread in my machine but it might be another completely seperate issue from the segfault.)

Comment: One of the reporters mentions gcc version dependency: "If I install g++ 4.8 and compile with that the segfault disappears and the op runs correctly." I would give version 4.8 a try. If it works I'd be pretty confident this is the same issue.

Comment: See my updates in the question.